# Difference between .section .text and .text with gas

Tags: x86, directive, gnu-assembler

As far as I can tell with objdump, with gas using

```
.section .text
```

and

```
.text
```

are equivalent. Is this true?

From gas manual [.section *name*](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC119):

> Use the `.section` directive to assemble the following code into a section named *name*.

From gas manual [.text *subsection*](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC131):

> Tells `as` to assemble the following statements onto the end of the text subsection numbered *subsection*, which is an absolute expression. If *subsection* is omitted, subsection number zero is used.

My question also applies to `.data`.

Comment: Yes, I think `.text` is just an alias / shortcut for `.section .text`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a small difference.

`.section` lets the programmer specify *any* section name and thus, as stated in the documentation, is not supported for the `a.out` format (while it is for *COFF* and *ELF*).

> This directive is only supported for targets that actually support arbitrarily named sections; on a.out targets, for example, it is not accepted, even with a standard a.out section name.

`.text` on the contrary always designates the code section regardless of its actual name in the output format.

Considering that [`a.out`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) was used *before* *ELF* was added back in the '96, I won't consider compatibility with such an old format an issue.

`.text` and `.data` save a few keystrokes but for consistency it's perfectly fine to always use `.section`.